# MongoDB - Not Authorized to add replica set member, but Mongo Auth is disabled

Tags: mongodb

My planned steps (my goal):

- Create 3x Mongo Hosts
- Initiate Replication (`rs.initiate()`)
- Add hosts to replication set
- Enable auth on primary (which *should* sync user/role/auth settings across cluster??)

Auth is disabled during the replica set config, however I'm getting "not authorized on local to execute command" when attempting to add a member.

Here are the steps I'm running on a fresh brand new Mongo install without auth enabled yet ---

Check that `--auth` is not enabled:

```
root@3106f5453c95:/# ps -ef |grep mongod
mongodb      1     0  1 16:34 ?        00:00:01 mongod --bind_ip_all --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

mongod.conf

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
   logAppend: true
replication:
   replSetName: rsprod
security:
   keyFile: /data/db/replicaSetKey.key
```

**The following commands are ran on one of the hosts in the 3 node set:**

Initiate replica set without issue:

```
root@b902fd176bdd:/# mongo --eval 'rs.initiate()'
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
{
    "info2" : "no configuration specified. Using a default configuration for the set",
    "me" : "b902fd176bdd:27017",
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1526490381, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1526490381, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Then adding a host (it's denied):

```
root@b902fd176bdd:/# mongo --eval 'rs.add("myhost.example.com:27017")'
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
2018-05-16T17:07:20.860+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: count failed: {
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1526490432, 1),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on local to execute command { count: \"system.replset\", query: {}, fields: {}, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1526490432, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 5DC7E35270B286518353EDADEBF474074AD1140A), keyId: 6556226268348547073 } }, $db: \"local\" }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1526490432, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"XcfjUnCyhlGDU+2t6/R0B0rRFAo="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6556226268348547073")
        }
    }
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBQuery.prototype.count@src/mongo/shell/query.js:383:11
DBCollection.prototype.count@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1584:12
rs.add@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1274:1
@(shell eval):1:1
```

My understanding is that auth roles were not a requirement of replica sets, so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem by searching around and finally found it.

Here is the cause of the whole problem:

> keyFile implies security.authorization.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.keyFile

So, if you use a KeyFile for the cluster, you MUST use authorization as well. This is pretty hidden in the documentation but clearly it's very important.

So the order of operations should be:

- Initialize databases
- Create Users/Roles
- Restart DB with auth enabled
- Configure replication

It's either that or don't use a keyFile for the cluster.